# How to use a C# DLL in Microsoft Access

Tags: c#, excel, ms-access

I have created the class below in Visual Studio 2019 with "Make Assembly COM-Visible" set to true and "Register for COM interop" checked.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace SimpleCalc
{

    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    [Guid("95F54E1A-826C-4766-9FE9-D32C47B07504")]
    public interface _Test
    {
        string HelloWorld { get; }
    }

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [Guid("9F7248AF-4E59-4938-AECC-B938703F33BB")]
    [ProgId("SimpleCalc.Test")]
    public class Test : _Test
    {
        public string HelloWorld { get { return "Hello, World! "; } }
    }
}
```

Code compiles fine and I can reference it in VBA and the property "Hello World" is shown in the class "Test" in the object browser.

However when I try to access in an onClick event subroutine with the code

```
Dim o As Test
Set o = New Test 
MsgBox o.HelloWorld
```

error:'429'  "ActiveX component can't create object" is generated at Set o = New Test.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a .Net DLL in Microsoft Access VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849001/using-a-net-dll-in-microsoft-access-vba)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all? You not marked the interface as public

eg;

```
    public interface _Test
```

Next up, I would remove the Prog_id - you don't need it, and I think that also messing this up.

And, really, I don't see any case to be made for building a infterface here? I doubt in c# (or for sure in VBA), you not going to need to declarer public member variable types derived from that class without having to create a instance of that class (it you need to do that - then ok - I suppose one can make the case for a interface, but OTHER then this reason? No need).

One does not really need to bother with the GUIDS in the code either. The project settings will take care of that.

And you don't really need a namespace - again project default takes care of that.

So, now we down to this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
public class COMTest1
    {
        public string HelloWorld
        {
            get
            {
                return "Hello, World! ";
            }
        }

    }
```

Ok, now that is much better!
Of course, we need to check the "com visible" box here:

[image]

or you can just above the the class interface type setting add a COMvisible=true.

And during development, you can (should) have the COM assembly registered. On target machines you have to do a regasm.exe, but on your dev box, you can get VS to do this for you. Eg here:

[image]

Now above does ZERO to the project - it ONLY does that regasm for you.

At this point, then in VBA, you can use late binding, or early. Assuming we set a refernce in tools->reference from VBA, like this:

[image]

And now our VBA code will look like this:

```
Sub Test23434324()

  Dim cTest As New CShapeCOMTest.ComTest1
  
  Debug.Print c.HelloWorld
  
End Sub
```

So, I would not bother with a interface - but yours was not public.

The above is all you really need for this to work. And in place of a interace, simply mark members as public or private. And this includes you dumping getters/setters.

You can just at the class level have this:

```
public class COMTest1
    {

public string CompanyName;
public string PhoneNumber;

        public string HelloWorld
        {
            get
            {
                return "Hello, World! ";
            }
        }

    }
```

And those pubic members will show up in VBA intel-sense.

So, I don't even bother with a interface.

I often don't bother with get/sets for simple public members (say a string)

As a general rule? Build a simple clean class - you only add the interface tag, no GUIDS, no nothing else and no need for the interface either. Most of my classes are written this way. So not much love and care required here.

In fact, you don't even need the Classinterface tag - you can just set the make com assembly true check box in the above assembly window. (but, you lose intei-sense on the VBA com side if you do this ).

The less code, the more we pair this down to the absolute min?

The less code to write, and the less problems to mess this up.

***Edit: ************************************

The working tested example is this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
public class COMTest1
    {

public string CompanyName;
public string PhoneNumber;

        public string HelloWorld
        {
            get
            {
                return "Hello, World! ";
            }
        }

    }
```

Force the project to x86. This will force regams.exe to correct register.
If you been running Access + testing - you have to exit access else the .dll gets locked when it runs that code.

Remember to set under assembly MAKE assembly COM visible.

Remember to check register for com interop (build tab on project).

With above, in VBA, you even see intel-sense like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you that is far better. Can reference in VBA OK but when program tries to execute "Debug.Print cTest.HelloWorld" it still throws the error error "'429' ActiveX component can't create object".

Comment: see my above edit - force your project to x86 - don't use ANY.

Comment: Recompiled as x86, Intel-sense is exactly as you have shown but still getting the same error. I am going to try with Excel to see if it works.

Comment: gee, this is perplexing. Perhaps you running office x64 then? (but then that reference would not show up - especially since we force to x86. You could do a clean project - that will un-register the .dll.  Then do a re-build. But given that you were able to set a reference, then this is strange. (Excel un-likely to make a difference).  I would un-reference in Access. Exit, and then do a clean project in vs (this will un-register the com object).  I zipped and posted to skydriver here - you can try my above project: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Avrwal_LV4qxhponPXsGp-Lur6w1SA?e=alGMWV

Comment: Hi Albert. Problem is with my laptop, tried on PC and worked fine. Must have set something somewhere, could take some finding!!!!

Comment: At least you have a base working template here. And an interface would not have helped. Things as absolute min working is a good start and over time, say introduce a interface (there are good reasons but in most cases no benefits exist having to code up the interface0. Same goes for get/sets - often a simple public var gets you the same - and again less code.  There is a big reason why "hello world" programs are popular - (we start with the most min working example possible, and THEN work up from that). REMEMER you need to launch VS as admin else COM registrations will fail in most cases.